# While code, Method, Int to boolean understanding

Tags: java, loops, methods, while-loop

I'm reviewing some code for a college assignment and we've been given examples to assist us.
I'm little confused on what the below is doing as it's using the assignment operator instead of the .equals or == method.

If I replace the code with the == (and create a local variable to compare it to) the code starts infinite looping and displaying out the default value.

```
 int select = 0;
 
  do {
    
        switch (select) {
            case 1:
                Problem();
                break; 
            default:
            System.out.println("Invalid");
            break;
            } 

    } while ((select = getSelection()) !=3);

 public static int getSelection () { 
(Return function here with has.nextInt and scanner class to receive input)
}
```

From my limited understanding, the above assigns "Select" to the value from the "getSelection" method, it's also stating do not accept inputs that are 3 e.g. System.exit0 at this point.

Have I understood correctly?

(Further example as requested)
I would do something along the lines of:

```
int select = 0; 
int select1 = 0; 
    do {

    switch (select) {
        case 1:
            Problem();
            break; 
        default:
        System.out.println("Invalid");
        break;
        } 
 } while (select == select1);
```

I am attempting to think of a logical equivalent to the lecturers example but seem to be unable to do this without breaking the while loop.

Comment: This loop will run until user enters 3 in the input

Comment: Please show how you have used `==` here. `(select == getSelection()) !=3` wouldn't compile, and I'm not sure how a local variable would change that.

Comment: I have added the example for you :)

Comment: In the second example you do not change any of `select` or `select1` inside `do-while` loop -- that's why it is infinite.  You need to add `select = getSelection();` after the `switch` -- then the loop runs while 0 is returned by `getSelection()`

Answer (score 4):

In java, (and other "C like" languages) the result of an assignment is the value assigned, ie this code:

```
do {
    // other code
} while ((select = getSelection()) !=3)
```

is the same as:

```
do {
    // other code
    select = getSelection();
} while (select != 3)
```

This style, known as *in-line conditional*, is generally considered a style to be avoided.

There is a checkstyle violation for it - see [AvoidInlineConditionals](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_coding.html#AvoidInlineConditionals)